Mismatch between postgres versions in docker (postgres and node images)
Not sure whether this is the right platform for this. It is on the boundary between programming and DevOps.
I have an application that consists of 2 containers: a database container with the postgres image and web server container with the node image. Now, the database container runs the latest postgres version, which is postgres 17, but the node container is based on debian bookworm, where the latest postgres package has version 15. I try to make backups with pg_dump from the node container, but this currently gives a version mismatch.
Would it be wise to downgrade my postgres server, or somehow install a newer version of postgres in the node container? Or is there an entirely different fix altogether?

Backing up your database is essential, but I wouldn't necessarily consider it a "programming" task.  In addition to [devops.se] there's also a dedicated [dba.se] site.

Surely it makes sense to run the pg_dump in your database container? That is always going to match the server version exactly.

@RichardHuxton Is there an easy way to initiate this from the other container, and get the results back? How hacky is it to SSH between docker containers?

SSH is certainly how I'd do it with real machines rather than containers.

... where the latest postgres package has version 15 only applies if you are using the Debian repo. If you use the  PGDG Repo you can get all currently supported Postgres versions.

@AdrianKlaver Thanks. That is indeed the solution I will use.
